# Envers only Audit delete

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-envers

I have a class audited by envers. For this specific class only need audit in delete .
How make this?
thanks

My class:

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyClass{...}
```

Comment: You should configure Enver's `AuditEventListener` to react only on `post-delete` events. I believe this is discussed in official Enver documentation.

Comment: Most of the classes must audit at high loss and modification. Only one must be to delete.

Comment: In this case, you will have to roll your custom plugin to Enver by subclassing appropriate things. See [there](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_conditional_auditing)

Comment: Thanks. This is a solution, but I made a mistake not telling that I'm working with Envers 3.6.6 
Exist solution for this version?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `DefaultAuditStrategy`, the best approach to doing this would be to subclass all the various event listeners in order to only react in the delete listener as suggested in the comments using [Conditional Auditing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_conditional_auditing).

On the other hand if you're using the `ValidityAuditStrategy`, I would highly recommend against using the conditional auditing technique as that approach doesn't work well using that specific audit strategy.

The approach to conditional auditing is being overhauled in Envers 6.0,  allowing it to be more flexible and less intrusive on users to override listener behavior directly.